# how to calculate percent conditional aggregation

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table of data, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cf72da/5
Using a pivot statement, I am able to break down the count by title

```
select division, status, 
       sum(case when title = 'worker' then 1 else 0 end) as workerCount,
       (sum(case when title = 'worker' then 1 else 0 end) /
        sum(sum(case when title = 'worker' then 1 else 0 end)) over ()
       )*100 as workerPercent
from ta
group by status, division
order by division, status
```

So the result looks like this:

```
DIVISION  STATUS    WORKERCOUNT  WORKERPERCENT
11        ready     3            30
11        started   3            30
12        finished  4            40
12        ready     0            0
12        started   0            0
```

I actually need the percentages divided by the division, for example

```
DIVISION  STATUS    WORKERCOUNT  WORKERPERCENT
11        ready     3            50
11        started   3            50
12        finished  4            100
12        ready     0            0
12        started   0            0
```

Any idea how I can accomplish this with SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query:

```
select division, status, 
       sum(case when title = 'worker' then 1 else 0 end) as workerCount,
       (sum(case when title = 'worker' then 1 else 0 end) /
        sum(sum(case when title = 'worker' then 1 else 0 end)) over (PARTITION BY division)
       )*100 as workerPercent
from ta
group by status, division
order by division, status
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the *analytic clause*:

```
select division, status, 
       count(decode(title,'worker',1,null)) as workerCount,
       ( count(decode(title,'worker',1,null))
       / sum(count(decode(title,'worker',1,null))) over(partition by division)
       )*100 as workerPercent
from ta
group by status, division
order by division, status
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to your expected result.

You just need to add the `partition by` clause in the `analytical function` as following:

> ```
> SQL> SELECT
>   2      DIVISION,
>   3      STATUS,
>   4      SUM(CASE WHEN TITLE = 'worker' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS WORKERCOUNT,
>   5      ( SUM(CASE WHEN TITLE = 'worker' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) /
>   6              SUM(SUM(CASE WHEN TITLE = 'worker' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
>   7                  OVER( PARTITION BY DIVISION )  -- Changes here
>   8      ) * 100 AS WORKERPERCENT
>   9  FROM TA
>  10  GROUP BY STATUS, DIVISION
>  11  ORDER BY DIVISION, STATUS;
>
>   DIVISION STATUS               WORKERCOUNT WORKERPERCENT
> ---------- -------------------- ----------- -------------
>         11 ready                          3            50
>         11 started                        3            50
>         12 finished                       4           100
>         12 ready                          0             0
>         12 started                        0             0
>
> SQL>
> ```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cf72da/26)

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

As other posters have pointed out, you can (and should) use analytic functions for this kind of problem.

Specifically for your use case, there is the `RATIO_TO_REPORT` function - much better to use it than to compute things "manually" as in your attempt and in several Answers.

Note another change I made - sum of 1 when "worker" and 0 "otherwise" is the same as counting "worker". `COUNT` is much clearer than `SUM` in this context.

```
select division, status, 
       count(case when title = 'worker' then 1 end) as workerCount,
       ratio_to_report(count(case when title = 'worker' then 1 end))
           over (partition by division)*100 as workerPercent
from  ta
group by status, division
order by division, status;
```

Thank you for posting the test data and your attempt - that is extremely helpful!